# Postgresql Join elements by key with json fields

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate

*Join elements by key with json fields*

```
CREATE TABLE customer_json (
   ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   info json NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO customer_json (info) VALUES ('{ "customer": ["John Doe"]}');
INSERT INTO customer_json (info) VALUES ('{ "customer": ["Peter Doe"]}');
INSERT INTO customer_json (info) VALUES ('{ "customer": ["Welsey Doe"]}');
```

```
select  json_agg(info) from customer_json
```

**Result:**

```
[
   { "customer": ["John Doe"]},
   { "customer": ["Peter Doe"]},
   { "customer": ["Welsey Doe"]}
]
```

**Wanted:**

```
[
   { "customer": [
                    "John Doe",
                    "Peter Doe",
                    "Welsey Doe"
                 ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1deb931125cd481a3dc8fae3db10fe4c)

```
SELECT
    json_agg(object)
FROM (
    SELECT
        json_build_object(
            'customer',
           json_agg(info -> 'customer' -> 0)
        ) as object
    FROM 
        customer_json
) s
```

1. Get the names with `info -> 'customer' -> 0` (first getting the value JSON array of `customer` and then get their first value)
2. aggregate them into one JSON array with `json_agg()`
3. Build a new JSON object with json_build_object() and putting the new array from step 2 as value
4. Because you want to get this customer object into a second array, you could use `json_agg()` as second group using a superior query.

---

Alternatively, instead doing step 4, you could use json_build_array() in your special case:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=07793efb0ade0223b524f4c135309062)

```
SELECT
    json_build_array(
        json_build_object(
            'customer',
           json_agg(info -> 'customer' -> 0)
        )
     )
FROM 
    customer_json
```

Comment: @TiagoSa Did this help? Should something be changed? Please do not to forget to upvote ANY answer that helped in any way. This honors the time and work the repliers spend into your problem. If one answer solves your problem, then please do not forget to accept it as well, to close the question.